# how to group a field and check some condition in a faster way

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file as a input it contains data of 4 fields like [001|00|002|G1] this totally 20k records. i need to group based on first field [001] and check for the condition of last field [G1] and write on to a file and continue grouping next data for ex[002] and check for the last field and write into a file. for this i need a linq. i tried to create a list distinct first field and then checked with actual input file but it has 20k records so it takes so much of time so i need linq to reduce time. thank you

Comment: Would you please give some exact code representation of the original and the grouped data structure?

Comment: 001|00|002|G1 , 002|09|008|R3 ,002|10|012|H1 , 002|99|090|G1 , 003|99|002|R1 ,  003|00|002|G1 , etc this is the file format. Here I'm giving 6 lines as a example like this 20k lines. First I need to group 001 as a group and check for last field G1 and should not print. Then I need to group all three  002  as a group and check each lines last field R3 , H1 , G1 and print all 3 record if any one is not G1. Then group 003 and check for same for this I need linq

Answer (score 0):

So you have a file with comma separated strings, where every string contains for items separated by a vertical bar. You won't to manipulate the data in your file.

First of all: good programming needs separation of concerns. You need to separate the way that your data is stored (a file with a certain format) from what the actual data.

This means, that you need to have a function to read the storage to produce the data. A separate method will manipulate the data.

This has the advantage, that if you need the same file to manipulate it otherwise, you don't have to rewrite the reading of the file. Or if you decide to use a different file format, for instance a proper CSV file, or a database, you don't have to rewrite the data manipulation part.

So let's separate your problem into smaller parts:

1. Read the file into a stream of characters and divide the stream of characters into a sequence of strings. Each string is the part between commas, without the whitespaces
2. Convert the sequence of strings into a sequence of the data that it represents
3. Do your data manipulation

To make the functions look more LINQ like, I'll use extension methods. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

(1) Read the file to get a sequence of characters. For this we create an extension method for TextReader.

```
public static class ExtensionsForTextReader
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines (this TextReader reader, char delimiter)
    {
        reader.ReadLines(delimiter, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines (this TextReader reader,
        char delimiter,
        IEqualityComparer<char> comparer)
    {
        // TODO: exception if no reader

        // if no comparer given, use default comparer
        if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<char>.Default;

        List<char> chars = new List<char> ();
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            char c = (char)reader.Read ();

            if (c == delimiter) {
                yield return new String(chars.ToArray());
                chars.Clear ();
                continue;
            }

            chars.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

This was easy and fairly straightforward.

(2) Convert the sequence of strings into a sequence of the data that it represents

I don't know what your data means, so let's call it MyData:

```
class MyData
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
    public int C {get; set;}
    public string D {get; set;}
}
```

We also need extension methods for strings that will convert every string that with a delimiter to an object of MyData:

```
public static MyData ToMyData(string text)
{
     return text.ToMyData('|');
}

public static MyData ToMyData(string text, char delimiter)
{
     // TODO: exception if text equals null
     // TODO: maybe you want to remove starting and trailing whitespaces

     // we'll split the text into four separate strings using ToStrings defined above
     using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(text))
     {
          // I expect exactly 4 strings. Decide what to do if less or more
          ICollection<string> textParts = textReader.ToStrings(delimiter)
              .Take(5)
              .ToList();
          if (textParts.Count == 4)
          {
              return new MyData
              {
                  A = Int32.Parse(textParts[0],
                  B = Int32.Parse(textParts[1],
                  C = Int32.Parse(textParts[2],
                  D = textParts[3],
              };
          }
          // else TODO: decide what to do if incorrect input format
     }
}
```

The same for a sequence of strings:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyData> ToMyData(this IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
     return lines.Select(line => line.ToMyData();
}
```

For completeness, you can write an overload with a delimiter and a comparer.

This is all you need to convert from your storage into the data that is stored in it. Less than half a page of code.

```
// read the file and produce a sequence of MyData
using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    IEnumerable<MyData> = textReader.ReadLines(',').ToMyData('|');

    // TODO: process the sequence of MyData
}
```

Now we can finally focus on your data manipulation.

> First I need to group 001 as a group and check for last field G1 and should not print. Then I need to group all three 002 as a group and check each lines last field R3 , H1 , G1 and print all 3 record if any one is not G1.

The grouping won't be the problem. The result is a group with key 001, or 002, etc, and values the MyData objects that have A == 001

If any of the D values in the group equal "G1", then the group should not be in the end result.

```
var groupsWithSameAWithoutG1 = textReader.ReadLines(',')
    .ToMyData('|')

    // make groups with same value for A:
    .GroupBy(data => data.A)

    // keep only those groups that have no groupMember with D == "G1"
    .Where(group => !group.Where(groupMember => groupMember.D).Any());
```

You wrote: "and print all records if any one is not G1". So let's print the remaining items:

```
foreach (var group in groupsWithSameAWithoutG1)
{
    Print(group.Key)
    foreach (MyData groupMember in group)
    {
        Print(groupMember.B);
        Print(groupMember.C);
        Print(groupMember.D);
    }
}
```

Because you separated the storage of your data (file) from the manipulation, it is easy to change the storage device, or to change the layout of the storage to for instance JSON, without having to rewrite the code manipulation.

Similarly: if you need different manipulations, for instance if you want the first 7 items with B == 5, ordered by ascending C, you can use the same file conversion methods

```
var DataWithBIs5 = textReader.ReadLines(',').ToMyData('|')
    .Where(data => data.B == 5)
    .OrderBy(data => data.C)
    .Take(7);
```